# Mobile browser and 100% x 100% fixed elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have got a problem with my page. I have a parent

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Then I have an fixed element:

```
.full-screen-content.is-visible {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100vw;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: visible;
    pointer-events: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 999999999;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
```

Inside of that fixed element I have got an absolute element which is 100% x 100% as well.

The problem is when I'm watching my popup on mobile browser and URL bar is dropped down everything is ok, when I'm at the bottom of the popup and dragging down then URL bar is hiding and popup is not 100% height but 100% - URL Bar height. When I get off my finger from screen then popup is 100% of viewport.

I was trying to set height automaticly in JS by continuous code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($(window).width() < mobileBreak) {
        var documentHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
        $('#js-works-container').css('height',documentHeight);
        $('#js-scroll-wrap').scroll(function() {
            var documentHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
            $('#js-works-container').css('height',documentHeight);
        });
    }
});
```

Here is a screenshot from mobile:

[image]

I'm also wondering why my Close button which is set to `top: 20px` and has static size is always 20px from top of the page and it's scaling correctly even if the URL bar is showing. Help me guys please, because i don't know that to do.

[Here's a link to the page](http://dev.openform.pl/our-works/national-museum-in-krakow)

Comment: better use `$('html').height()` then `$(window)`, did you try the vh  `height:100vh`

Comment: I was trying to set `height: 100vh` but it was working exact the same as `height: 100%`. `$('html').height()` doesn't changed anything.

Comment: better if you set the height of the body to the height of the viewport ,hide the overflow

Comment: Didn't changed anything, i want my popup to be 100%, he has scrollable content inside anyways, if i set `$('html').height` it was `16000px`. Also overflow is hidden on body :(

Comment: did you tried to add: `body, html { height: 100%; width:100%;}` ?

Comment: I was trying, nothing happens, look at the screenshot, Close Button has allways good position from top, but my popup haven't got, both of them are just right after body, and have fixed position, set top and width and height... i don't know what to do else... :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on('scroll resize', function() {
    checkPopupHeight();
});

function checkPopupHeight() {
  var documentHeight = $(window).height();
  var popupHeight = $('#js-works-container').height();
  if(documentHeight !== popupHeight) {
    $('#js-works-container').css('height',documentHeight);
  }
}
```